# How to make fast row calculation in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance, gridview, row

I am developing asp.net webform application with gridview control. I have grid control which is having more than 20 rows. Each rows having 4 columns like Ordered, Ex-Received, Current-Receiving and Pending. Here, Current-Receiving column having input box to enter the qty. Once entered the qty, Pending Columns will show the Pending qty in the corresponding row after calculate done (Pending Qty = Ordered - (Ex-Received + Current-Receiving) . And in footer sum of pending and sum of receiving qty will show. It working fine if i have 4 or 5 rows. If i have more than and above 15 rows, it takes time to calculate. Please find below my code which is written in current-receiving input box text_changed event. Any idea to make it faster ? In future, rows count will increase like 50 or more.

```
    Dim textBox1 As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    Dim dt As New DataTable      

    Dim RowIndex As Integer = CType(CType(sender, TextBox).NamingContainer, GridViewRow).RowIndex

    Dim glblRcvdRolls As Label =grd.Rows(RowIndex).FindControl("lblRcvdRolls")
    '
    Dim glblOrdRolls As Label = grd.Rows(RowIndex).FindControl("lblOrdRolls")

    Dim glblPendWt As Label = grd.Rows(RowIndex).FindControl("lblPendWt")
    If textBox1.Text = "" Then textBox1.Text = 0
    If glblRcvdRolls.Text = "" Then glblRcvdRolls.Text = 0
    If glblOrdRolls.Text = "" Then glblOrdRolls.Text = 0

'Each Row Calculations
    glblPendWt.Text = Convert.ToInt32(glblOrdRolls.Text) - (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(glblRcvdRolls.Text))
    If Convert.ToInt32(glblPendWt.Text) < 0 Then
        glblPendWt.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow
    Else
        glblPendWt.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    End If

' Total Row Calculations 
    Dim mPendQty As Double = ViewState("PndQty")
    Dim mRcvdQty As Double = ViewState("RcvdQty")
    If IsNumeric(glblPendWt.Text) Then mPendQty += Convert.ToDouble(glblPendWt.Text)
    If IsNumeric(textBox1.Text) Then mRcvdQty += Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text)
    ViewState("PndQty") = mPendQty
    ViewState("RcvdQty") = mRcvdQty

    grd.FooterRow.Cells(5).Text = mRcvdQty
    grd.FooterRow.Cells(6).Text = mPendQty

'Setfocus after postback - otherwise focus will set somewhere in the form.
    If RowIndex <=grd.Rows.Count Then
        Dim grdNRText As TextBox = grd.Rows(RowIndex + 1).FindControl("txtRcvdQty")
        'grdNRText.Focus()
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "focus", "document.getElementById('" + grdNRText.ClientID + "').focus();document.getElementById('" + grdNRText.ClientID + "').select();", True)
    Else
        'btnInward.Focus()
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "focus", "document.getElementById('" + btnInward.ClientID + "').focus();document.getElementById('" + btnInward.ClientID + "').select();", True)
    End If


    Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am betting that your main issue and problem is the the code you have, but in fact that on page load, you re-binding the grid.

The fact that you started adopting JavaScript to set the focus is the tell tell sign here.

You should not in ANY case re-bind the grid each time. Remember, for ANY post-back, the page load event will fire. And there should be no need to persist the two total values you have.

So, if you have a data source on the page - I would remove it - load the GV in code.

You should be able to use the server side .Focus() method of the control (and I see at one time you had or were attempting to use that, and now are using JavaScript. You should NOT have to do that.

So, in the last 100, or in fact 200 web pages I had made, the page load event MUST check the isPostBack, and ONLY ONE time do you run ANY code, and ANY code to bind.

Here is a example grid, and I have TWO columns that can post back (text boxes), one is Qty, and the other is Price (I used Qty in code - it was displaed as nights).

Take a close look. If you ahve any combo box binding code - again, it should ONLY run one time - in row data bound event.

And if you want, you can drop the whole thing into a update panel - but it not required.

So, say this markup:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
            ShowFooter="True" CssClass="table">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nights" SortExpression="Nights">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNights" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nights") %>'
                            OnTextChanged="txtNights_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
                            TextMode="Number">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>'
                            OnTextChanged="txtPrice_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
                            TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tamount" 
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"  FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Tamount") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                     <FooterTemplate >
                        <asp:Label ID="LblTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                    </FooterTemplate>                        
                </asp:TemplateField>                
            </Columns>                
        </asp:GridView>
```

Ok, now our code - remember - ONLY bind the GV ONE time, NEVER again.

So the grid looks like this:

[image]

Our code to load the Grid

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(
            "SELECT top 10 * FROM tblHotels WHERE Description is not null ORDER BY HOtelName", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()
            SumRows()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Ok, that's it - don't re- bind the gv.

Now, here are the two code stubs for the two text boxes (qty, price), and auto postback = true.

```
Protected Sub txtNights_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim tQty As TextBox = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = tQty.NamingContainer
    Call RowCalc(gRow)

    ' we were in Qty control - set focus to next (price) control
    Dim tPrice As TextBox = gRow.FindControl("txtPrice")
    tPrice.Focus()

    SumRows()

End Sub

Protected Sub txtPrice_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim tPrice As TextBox = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = tPrice.NamingContainer
    Call RowCalc(gRow)
    SumRows()

    ' we in Price - we jump to next row below (or cycle to first row)

    Dim gRowNext As GridViewRow = Nothing
    If gRow.RowIndex + 1 < GridView1.Rows.Count Then
        gRowNext = GridView1.Rows(gRow.RowIndex + 1)
    Else
        ' jump to top row
        gRowNext = GridView1.Rows(0)
    End If
    Dim tQty As TextBox = gRowNext.FindControl("txtNights")
    tQty.Focus()

End Sub

Sub RowCalc(gRow As GridViewRow)

    Dim tQty As TextBox = gRow.FindControl("txtNights")
    Dim tPrice As TextBox = gRow.FindControl("txtPrice")
    Dim lblAmount As Label = gRow.FindControl("lblAmount")

    lblAmount.Text = Nz(tQty.Text, 0) * Nz(tPrice.Text, 0)

End Sub
```

In fact, we have MORE code to set the focus to the next control then quite much the actuall work.

And since I had TWO controls that can change, then I built a common routine for both controls to call (RowCalc).

```
Sub RowCalc(gRow As GridViewRow)

    Dim tQty As TextBox = gRow.FindControl("txtNights")
    Dim tPrice As TextBox = gRow.FindControl("txtPrice")
    Dim lblAmount As Label = gRow.FindControl("lblAmount")

    lblAmount.Text = Nz(tQty.Text, 0) * Nz(tPrice.Text, 0)

End Sub
```

And, of course the code to sum the rows - total into footer is this:

But NOTE carefully - I don't have to persist that total value - it will and should survive post-backs.

```
Sub SumRows()
    ' sum value - set footer total value
    Dim MyTotal As Double

    For Each gRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim lblAmount As Label = gRow.FindControl("lblAmount")
        MyTotal += Nz(lblAmount.Text, 0)
    Next

    Dim lblTotal As Label = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblTotal")
    lblTotal.Text = MyTotal

End Sub
```

And I used a nz() function - since I did a abone head move, and allowed nulls as the default for those number rows - not 0.

Not a huge deal, but I have this for nz()

```
Public Function Nz(ByVal Value As Object, Optional ByVal MyDefault As Object = 0) As Object
    If Value Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Value) OrElse (Value.ToString = "") Then
        Return MyDefault
    Else
        Return Value
    End If
End Function
```

Now, with 20, or even 30 rows - it is butter smooth, and I can't tell difference speed wise with 5 rows, or 30. And you should find the same results.

So, my spider sense suggests that you have some wonkey code running each time on page load. Keep in mind that any button, any post-back WILL run the page load event each time.

So, ensure that you only EVER load up the GV one time, and don't re-bind, as that will for sure make this run slow.

Try some of the above ideas and code - but do check/address the first page load and only load/bind the GV one time.

## Edit: Don't allow nor use a post back - do this 100% client side

So, of course for really amazing performance, the solution of course is to do this 100% client side code - in the browser. This will be instant, and better yet, no post back required at all.

So, dump the auto post backs, and now our Qty, and Price controls look like this - with a js code on change event.

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nights">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNights" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nights") %>'
                            OnTextChanged="txtNights_TextChanged" onchange="myjscalc(this,'txtNights')"
                            TextMode="Number">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>'
                            OnTextChanged="txtPrice_TextChanged" onchange="myjscalc(this,'txtPrice')"
                            TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tamount" 
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"  FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Tamount") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                     <FooterTemplate >
                        <asp:Label ID="LblTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                    </FooterTemplate>                        
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

And now the script for this is this:

```
        <script>
            function myjscalc(ctl, tid) {

                var Qty = $('#' + ctl.id.replace(tid, 'txtNights'))
                var Price = $('#' + ctl.id.replace(tid, 'txtPrice'))
                var tAmount = $('#' + ctl.id.replace(tid, 'lblAmount'))
                var n = Qty.val() * Price.val()
                tAmount.text(n.toFixed(2))

                // now total
                var MyTotal = 0.0
                var rowCount = $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr").length;
                rowCount = rowCount - 2 // remove header row, and footer from count

                for (var iRow = 0; iRow < rowCount; iRow++) {
                    tAmount = $('#GridView1_lblAmount_' + iRow)
                    MyTotal = MyTotal + + tAmount.text()
                }
                $('#GridView1_LblTotal').text(MyTotal.toFixed(2))
            }
  </script>
```

So, elimination of the post-back and doing this 100% client side ALSO fixes the focus issue. And any change will update instant - including the final total.